# Contact information of customers downloading the app

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have a free iOS app available on iOS App-store.
Sales and Trends section of ITunesConnect gives the information about number of downloads, country from where app is downloaded etc.

But how can I get the contact information of people who downloaded the app?

Answer (score 3):

This is illustrated in the **Apple Privacy Policy** and in the **iOS Developer License Agreement** and the **Mac Developer License Agreement** and finally in the [**Apple Review Guidelines**](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html#privacy)

17 - Privacy

17.1 - Apps cannot transmit data about a user without obtaining the user's prior permission and providing the user with access to information about how and where the data will be used

**17.2 Apps that require users to share personal information, such as email address and date of birth, in order to function will be rejected ** -- Mainly this one for you

17.3 - Apps may ask for date of birth (or use other age-gating mechanisms) only for the purpose of complying with applicable children's privacy statutes, but must include some useful functionality or entertainment value regardless of the user's age

Note that under **17.2** of the [Apple Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html#privacy) apps that require users to share there person date will be rejected, this includes Date of Birth, Email, Contact Details etc.

In section **17.1** one data that you do which to get from the user has to have there consent and the why you have asked this question it sounds like you wish for the data to be sent automatically which the user wouldn't know about so. **NO this can't be done.**

**NOTE**

Finally I am going to point you here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/182380#182380. This is because I have seen multiple questions from yourself that lack any research into the question beforehand, I tried to tell you exactly where to look in the comments and you still failed to do so. I know you have access to the [Apple Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html#privacy) as you have add a guideline from it on a previous question.

**Please carry out research before asking a question**

Comment: I guess you misinterpreted my question. My question was not "Is it ok If I ask user to share his/her personal information in order to function well?". My question was "Is there a way I can get the contact details of the customers who are downloading my app from App store?" Is there any mechanism Apple provides which I am not aware of that provides me necessary information as Apple provides about the number of downloads, country from where app has been downloaded etc.?

Comment: Lastly I apologize if my questions has shown lack of research but in reality thats not the case. May be I should provide more information about my question to make it more clear. I already told you that I will keep that in mind.

Comment: @MaddyOven Right, firstly as this is a development forum I have answered your question from a development point of view. Anything regarding users information from the app store or App is covered across 4 privacy bullet points (I have missed one but it relents to children). If this is about a specific piece of software (itunesconnect, itunes) then you are in completely the wrong place. That is not what Stackoverflow is for. You need to be going http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/itunes-connect to ask that sort of question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't unless they choose to enter that information in the app itself.  That would be a violation of Apple's privacy policy.

One way to do this on the app side would be implement Facebook login and get their Facebook information which includes most of their basic contact information.  (You should tell your users you are doing so.)

Comment: If you choose to do this using the facebook why. You will have to include such information that you will be getting user information based on facebook data in your own privacy policy which is an optional field to fill in but because you are getting user data you would be required to provide a privacy policy.